# Android, replace imagebutton on activity start

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am a noob so forgive me if the question is very basic, still learning from a book and experimenting.

I have a bunch of image buttons in a xml file (main.xml), when my activity starts (main_act.java) i want to replace all the other imagebuttons (except for the first) with another graphic (that says "disabled" on it, how do I do that?

(It will be  based on an if() condition, i figured that out... but the replacing part is whats confusing me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use ID to differ them, you can assign id to any element in your XML, you can assign id using XML attribute like this:

```
android:id="@+id/button1"
```

and access the in the code like this:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

with every button having ID, the you can control them in programmatic way, to change image on an image button:

```
btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimageresource);
```

You can put `yourimageresource` bitmap image in resources/drawable.

Comment: Oh okay i will add it to my answer.

Comment: I am getting a force close when doing that :(

Comment: what is the error? are you sure you have the image in the right place? I am also still learning, but i just tried it and succeed on changing my ImageButton's image, so I posted here :)

Comment: Seems to be some other problem, i commented out the code and its still giving me a FC, will check, andif it works will select your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Sometimes when you change references in the xml files, the autogenerated file R will get screwy. Try going to Project > Clean and select your project. This may help fix you problem.

Comment: Tried what you wrote, it still is acting screwy... anyway, i have to go meet someone so will just say thanks again and select this answer. If i cant get it working will post a new topic with the new problem :) as I am sure your solution works :)